# (Anti-)hermitian structure on dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H$ be an (anti-)hermitian form on a complex vector space $V$.

1)Does $H$ induce a natural (anti-)hermitian form on the dual $V^*$?
2)Suppose $f$ is unitary with respect to $H$. Is there any natural way to make the transpose $f^T$ unitary with respect to something induced by $H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If $H$ is a Hermitian form on $V$, it induces an isomorphism $V\to V^*$ by $v\mapsto(u\mapsto H(u,v))$. Now that $V^*$ is identified in a specific way with $V$, it can have the same Hermitian form.

2) Let $f:V\to V$ be unitary, and let $\varphi_v\in V^*$ be given by $\varphi_v(u)=H(u,v)$. By the above identification, we have $\|\varphi_v\|=\|v\|$. By definition of the transpose operator, we have $$f^t(\varphi_v)(u)=\varphi_v(f(u))=H(f(u),v)=H(u,f^*(v)),$$ thus
$f^t(\varphi_v)$ is the functional identified with $f^*(v)$, and $\|f^t(\varphi_v)\|=\|f^*(v)\|$. Since $f$ is unitary, so is $f^*$, and finally $$\|f^t(\varphi_v)\|=\|f^*(v)\|=\|v\|=\|\varphi_v\|,$$ hence $f^t$ is unitary with respect to the induced Hermitian form.

Comment: Yes indeed thank you! But what about the transpose?

Comment: I changed my answer, please have another look.

Comment: ah yes! I see that the matrix of this induced hermitian form is the inverse of the transpose of the matrix of the initial form (which is the expected answer when one computes explicitly).